# JavaScript open in a new tab, not window in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I am using,

```
window.open("Download.php");
```

This file opens in a new tab for all browsers. But in Chrome, it opens in a new window. So I have tried:

```
window.open("Download.php",'_blank'); 
window.open("Download.php",'_new');
```

But it still opens in new window, not a tab. I don't know if this is a coding problem or default settings problem. I am using Chrome v31.0.1650.57 m.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/1400370

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: I have tried. But still problem is there.Any other way ?
I put my code in AJAX success side.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
var tab=window.open("Download.php",'_blank'); 
tab.focus();
```

### Steps to verify

create a html file with markup:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <script>
     function newTab(){
        var tab=window.open("http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-closures.html",'_blank'); 
        tab.focus();
     }
   </script>
   <a href="#" onclick="newTab()">Open Tab</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Open it in chrome and click the link.

Comment: Any default browser settings problem ah ?

Comment: success:function(msg){
   if(format=='PDF')
    window.open("Download.php");

Comment: This works on Firefox 89.0.2 (Desktop) & Edge 91 (Desktop, Chromium) in July 2021, thank you! Edit: I should mention that I used `onclick=window.open("httpexample.com","_blank").focus();`

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: you can't**. At least for now, the browser vendors view this as something that should strictly be left to users to define for themselves. You set your target to something that should be a new window, and the browser will use the user's preferences to decide whether it opens as a new window or a new tab.

**Long answer: There's a CSS property that would do this on the HTML side, but none of the browsers support it**. According to the proposal, you'd use `target-new: tab` for links that you explicitly want to open in a new tab, and `target-new: window` for those you want to open in a new window. I don't know of any DOM proposals to do something analogous to this on the JavaScript side.

Comment: short answer is as long as long answer :O