# Open two links in different tabs in the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a link, two pages should open in different tabs in the same window.I have used this code

```
jQuery("#open").on("click",function(){
    window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com","_blank");
});
```

The problem is that first link opens correctly in a different tab in the same window.But the second link is opening in a new window like a pop up window.
[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abinaya91/62rb2/6/)

Comment: Did you check this in firefox ?

Comment: In firefox it is working but it doesn't work in chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new tab, not window in Chrome browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067713/javascript-open-in-a-new-tab-not-window-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: That solution too doesn't work @lorefnon

Comment: refer this link for chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564392/open-multiple-tabs-on-a-single-window-by-a-single-click-using-javascript